# How to replace a template parameter in a given type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming

Given that a template parameter called `B` is of type `C<D>` (on instantiation), how can I construct `C<A>` from `B`?

Here is a minimalized extract from my code:

```
template<typename A>
class foo {
    template<typename B> // B is guaranteed to always be of the form C<D>
    // How to write a function here with return type C<A>?
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can do this with [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) of a [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter)

```
template<typename, typename>
struct meta {};

template<typename A, template<typename> typename C, typename B>
struct meta<A, C<B>> {
    using type = C<A>;
};
```

`meta<A, C<B>>::type` will be `C<A>`

if you want to have handling of default argument in basic cases

```
template<typename...>
struct meta {};

template<typename A, template<typename...> typename C, typename B, typename ... Ts>
struct meta<A, C<B, Ts...>> {
    using type = C<A, Ts...>;
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot; I read both answers and for me this is what worked best (to avoid the STL allocator mess):
`template<typename...>
    struct meta {};
    template<typename A, template<typename...> typename C, typename B, typename ... Ts>
    struct meta<A, C<B, Ts...>> {
        using type = C<A>; /*but we drop the template arguments after the first (thus taking the default ones!) */
    };`

That is, dropping the ellipsis in the second to last line (i.e. using the default arguments).

Answer (score 1):

First we write some machinery to replace a type in a template type instance:

```
template<class In, class Replace>
struct replace_first_type;
template<template<class...>class Z, class T0, class...Ts, class Replace>
struct replace_first_type<Z<T0, Ts...>, Replace> {
  using type=Z<Replace, Ts...>;
};

template<class In, class Replace>
using replace_first = typename replace_first_type<In,Replace>::type;
```

`replace_first< Z, X >` takes `Z`, pattern matches it against any `template<class...>`, grabs the first argument, and replaces it with `X`.

This won't work for `std::array<int, 7>` as `7` isn't a type, but will work for `std::vector<int>`; `vector` is actually `<T, A>` with a default argument.  The `template<class...>` pattern matches templates that take 0 or more classes.

We then apply it:

```
template<typename A>
class foo {
  template<typename B>
  using result = replace_first<B, A>;
};
```

now `foo<int>::template result< std::vector<double> >` is a `std::vector<int, std::alloctor<double>>`.  Which admittedly is a pretty stupid type.

If you have a function:

```
  template<class B>
  result<B> do_something() {
    return {};
  }
```

actually returns a value of that type.

We can fix the problem with `std::allocator<double>` above by recursively replacing the type we replaced...

```
template<class X, class Src, class Dest>
struct subst_type {
  using type=X;
};
template<class X, class Src, class Dest>
using subst_t = typename subst_type<X, Src, Dest>::type;
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts, class Src, class Dest>
struct subst_type<Z<Ts...>, Src, Dest> {
  using type=Z<subst_t<Ts, Src, Dest>...>;
};
template<class Src, class Dest>
struct subst_type<Src, Src, Dest> {
  using type=Dest;
};
```

and apply to replace first:

```
template<class In, class Replace>
struct replace_first_type;
template<template<class...>class Z, class T0, class...Ts, class Replace>
struct replace_first_type<Z<T0, Ts...>, Replace> {
  using type=Z<Replace, subst_t<Ts, T0, Replace>...>;
};
```

and now when we `foo<int>::result<std::vector<double>>` we get `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>` instead of `std::vector<int, std::allocator<double>>` (which is a useless type).

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/faad7094eb3561d3).

There is some possibility that we'll get something horribly wrong from recursively replacing `A` with `B` in the rest of the arguments of a template, but as noted we definitely get something horrible with common templates if we don't do it.

Comment: What are your thoughts on @Tyker's approach?

Comment: @Museful If you don't need to support `std::vector` his works great.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont it does support default template argument with c++17

Comment: @Tyker Ah, I missed that C++17 feature.  And it probably rebinds the allocator without the somewhat dangerous "replace everything" mine needs.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont yes the allocator needs to be rebined too. so no my way wouldn't work in c++17 on vector.

Comment: but any form of remplace everything can break things if it isn't specialized.

Comment: Hm, with the second approach, if I have something like: `template<typename, typename> struct pack {}` and then use: `replace_first<packer<float, float>` I get: `packer<int, int>` as a result which seems to be inconsistent - I want only the first type parameter to be replaced.

Comment: @EdgarRokjān Yes, it finds your first type in your template instance type list, and replaces it everwhere with the second, recursively.  It has problems.  So does the alternative.