# How to match C++ varadic template (parameter pack) to enum class

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'd like to [replace some template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51293607/how-to-replace-a-template-parameter-in-a-given-type) in a complicated type (a [SYCL accessor](https://registry.khronos.org/SYCL/specs/sycl-2020/html/sycl-2020.html#_interface_for_buffer_command_accessors)), but some of the template parameters are enum classes, and some are plain class/struct types.

The following example illustrates the basic idea.  It will not compile unless I explicitly write out all the enum classes.  It would be nice to gloss over those with a parameter pack, but "template" doesn't seem to match "enum class".

```
enum class Animal {
    Fox, Gox
};
enum class Food {
    Gruel
};

template <typename T, int D, Animal A, Food F>
struct Blah {
};

template<typename, typename>
struct apply_accessor {};
/* Does not work, "class" doesn't match "enum class X". */
template<template<typename,int,class...> typename Acc, 
         typename T1, typename T, int D,
         class ... Ts>
struct apply_accessor<Acc<T1, D, Ts...>, T> {
    using type = Acc<T, D, Ts...>;
};
/* Could work, but only matches animal sequences. */
template<template<typename,int,Animal...> typename Acc, 
         typename T1, typename T, int D, Animal... A>
struct apply_accessor<Acc<T1, D, A...>, T> {
    using type = Acc<T, D, A...>;
};
/* Works, but really?
template<template<typename,int,Animal,Food> typename Acc, 
         typename T1, typename T, int D, Animal A, Food F>
struct apply_accessor<Acc<T1, D, A, F>, T> {
    using type = Acc<T, D, A, F>;
};*/

int main() {
    Blah<int,1,Animal::Fox,Food::Gruel> x;
    Blah<int,1,Animal::Gox,Food::Gruel> y;

    typename apply_accessor<decltype(x), float>::type z;
}
```

Note: it seems that for non-parameter packs, the opposite question [has also appeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807629/ensure-template-parameter-is-an-enum-class).
Note: probably the solution is C++17 <auto...> -- [Infer enum class type from enum class value template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960936/infer-enum-class-type-from-enum-class-value-template-parameter).

Answer (score 0):

This incantation succeeds, but requires C++17 compiler magic, which may prove dangerous to users.

```
template<template<typename,int,auto...> typename Acc,
         typename T1, typename T, int D,
         auto ... Ts>
struct apply_accessor<Acc<T1, D, Ts...>, T> {
    using type = Acc<T, D, Ts...>;
};
```